# Procedure to Create a Gmail Gadget

Tags: gmail, google-gadget, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I am trying to create a Contextual gadgets for my domain app's emails. Searched a lot for the procedures and followed the document published by Google.

Following steps are completed:

- Created manifest for the gadget.
- Created gadget XML and uploaded to a public server. Linked manifest with the Gadget.
- Verified manifest and deployed the app.

I can see the app in the top nav bar, but it is not triggered with the mail. I tried with Hello World example and many more, but failed to run the Gadget.

Is there any thing I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your test-mail triggers the gadget? The supplied hello world-example is case sensitive, so "Hello World" will trigger the gadget, but "hello world" won't.